# How do browsers analyze <tr> <td> without <table>?

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I write this, the browser will analyze normally.

```
<!-- <table border="1"> -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<!-- </table> -->
```

But I write like this, I find the browser will analyze them without any tags like string.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

is the same of

```
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Browsers will try to analyze and render the html even if it's not always valid. What is exactly your question?

Comment: @Esa: It's in the title: "how".

Answer (score 7):

Browsers ignore the `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` tags and the corresponding end tags. This has not been specified in HTML specifications, since they do not define the parsing of syntactically erroneous documents. In the HTML5 draft, however, there is a description that defines the browser behavior in a manner that corresponds to the what browsers actually do: [Tree construction](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tree-construction).

This means that you *cannot* write an HTML document that contains, say, a `<tr>` element outside a `table` element. The HTML parser in a browser simply does not construct such document trees. (You can, however, construct such a document dynamically with client-side scription.)