# google chrome remove automatically td when it is not in table and tr

Tags: html, google-chrome

I noticed to something strange:

when I write the following html (which I know it is not semantically correct)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>      
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <td><a>test</a></td>
    <td><a>test</a></td>
    <td><a>test</a></td>
    <td><a>test</a></td>
    <td><a>test</a></td>
</body>
</html>
```

after the page loads chrome decide to removes the td, you can see that in element inspector, but if you do Ctrl+u (view-source:)
you see that the td are there...

if I write the HTML like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>      
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <td><a>test</a></td>
        <td><a>test</a></td>
        <td><a>test</a></td>
        <td><a>test</a></td>
        <td><a>test</a></td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

it not remove anything it just add the tbody and tr after the page load.

why does it happen? let's say I want to use these tds afterwards with js manipulation?
also I did not understand why it is not consistent if it decide to remove I would expect it to remove in all cases.

I decided to share when auto fixing could cause another proble:
this is log from console:

```
// for second example
$('table > td')
[]

$('table >tbody >tr >td')
[<td>​…​</td>​, <td>​…​</td>​, <td>​…​</td>​, <td>​…​</td>​, <td>​…​</td>​]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In your first example you give out a non-standard HTML. The browser is eligible to interpret it as it wants. I assume that stripping the non-valid tags is valid. See [How do browsers analyze <tr> <td> without <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333870/how-do-browsers-analyze-tr-td-without-table) for more details
2. According to the standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html the tbody is optional. See [Why do browsers insert tbody element into table elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938083/why-do-browsers-insert-tbody-element-into-table-elements) to understand why the browser automagically adds the `tbody` element.

Comment: but I did not understand why it is not consistent if it decide to remove I would expect it to remove in all cases, any way I guess I will have to remember this behavior for the future, or just write it correctly :)