# jquery substr undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, substr

So I want to Substring the selected attribute, but i get the error:
"TypeError: src is undefined"

Heres the Code:

js

```
function reset_select(){
 var src = $('td.onedit').prop('id');
 var new_stuhl = src.substr(1, 1);
 ...
}
```

Html:

```
<tr>    
<td id="s1.1" class="names onedit"><p class="name">Name Name</p></td>
</tr>
```

console.log(src)  gives me the string 's1.1' and typeOf is 'string'. When I change

```
var src = "s1.1";
```

it works. I'm using jQuery 3.2.1.

Why does this not work? Is there soething wrong with the selector?

Comment: Why not write `$('#s1.1')`

Comment: You are missing the `table` tag in your markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) to have a `<table>` tag around your `<tr>` tags.

As mentioned by [@SandeepNayak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1273604/sandeep-nayak), you can read more about why in this question: [How do browsers analyze `<tr>` `<td>` without `<table>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333870/how-do-browsers-analyze-tr-td-without-table)

It works fine with it:

```js
function reset_select(){
     var src = $('td.onedit').prop('id');
     var new_stuhl = src.substr(1, 1);
     
     console.log(src);
     console.log(new_stuhl);
}

reset_select();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>    
        <td id="s1.1" class="names onedit"><p class="name">Name Name</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333870/how-do-browsers-analyze-tr-td-without-table) could be helpful as well